# Alternative way to use join in HQL update with Mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I am new to HQL and I need to do bulk update in HQL (no mysql query).

Here is a sample of my Entity

```
EnityA{
    int id,
    Date date,
    int criteria1,
    EntityB b;
}

EntityB{
   int id,
   status,
   List<EntityA> aas;
}
```

Now I want to update all As that has criteria1=1 and its corresponding EntityB status not equal to 6.

I just knew that hql doesn't support implicit or explicit joins, so there goes my thought of using them. Then I came across few blogs about using derived table. So I tried this query:

```
    update EntityA A set A.date= :someDate where A.id in 
(select temp.id from (select A1.id from EntityA A1 where A1.criteria=1 
and A1.b.status <> 6) as temp)
```

But unfortunately I am having `unexpected token: (` exception.

I guess it is because of derived table also not supported by HQL. Is there any way now. I really need to check status of EntityB.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You are right, HQL for DML could use subqueries, and these can use joins. If do observe your query properly, it could be rewrittern like this, and that should be working:

```
 update EntityA A set A.date= :someDate where A.id in 
 // (select temp.id from 
 (select A1.id from EntityA A1 where A1.criteria=1 and A1.b.status <> 6) 
 // as temp)
```

other words:

```
 update EntityA A set A.date= :someDate where A.id in 
 (select A1.id from EntityA A1 where A1.criteria=1 and A1.b.status <> 6)
```

#### [15.4. DML-style operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct)

> - ...
> - No Section 16.4, “Forms of join syntax”, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL query. **Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the subqueries themselves may contain joins.**

Comment: Hi @Radim 2nd option wont work because we are using implicit join. I tried first answer by escaping bracket but this doesnot work as well. Now I am having unexpected char \ excetion.

Comment: Well, I tested locally (with my entities) and it is working (with cross join filtered in where)... no escaping needed *(the second is the same as the first - just removed commented lines)*

Comment: Even this *(as expected)* is working for me `update EntityA A set A.date= :someDate where A.id in (select A1.id from EntityA A1 join A1.b B1 where A1.criteria=1 and B1.status <> 6)`

Comment: oh I am really sorry..I thought that was escaping (. But anyway I am amazed how did it work in your system, because i was having "you cannot specify target table "EntityA" " error which is why I tried derive table in first place. I think this is related to MySQL and you are probably using some other database

Comment: Oooops... Do not tell me that it could be the issue. You are right, I am using MS SQL - but that should not be problem for HIBRNATE. It is really cross platform in this case. Try my version above - with JOIN. Does that work?

Comment: thnks I will let you know asap but I am not keeping any hope in this..Because we are again referencing the same table

Comment: My point is: the first exception you've recieved (unexpected token '(') is really related to wrong HQL. My version is working ... but maybe it could really be that MySQL does not support that. Sorry then..

Comment: Yup same error.. can't we do anything about it. I think its mysql error. Is it that difficult to do such trivial thing in HQL (using Mysql).

Comment: I am sorry, but I won't have better answer for you. Because HQL is not related to any DB. It is just HQL (hiberante query language) which is due to dialects (in your case MySAL) converted into SQL. So, that either is limitation of your DB engine... or there could be bug in Dialect. Anyhow... my versions are working with MS SQL. So, to me it seems a bit weird ... wish to have better answer ;(